# Combine SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to select different column from different row from the same table with one statement . How will I combine this to be one?

```
SELECT `shop_lat_log` FROM `customers` WHERE `phoneNumber`='254719401837'
SELECT `delivery_lat_log` FROM `customers` WHERE `phoneNumber`='25472054919'
```

Comment: You should just select the two rows you need or do two queries; this will only make things confusing and hard to maintain as the same field will either not exist for different rows or it will have a different meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use each of two current queries as subqueries in one select statement:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT shop_lat_log FROM customers WHERE phoneNumber = '254719401837') AS shop_lat_log,
    (SELECT delivery_lat_log FROM customers WHERE phoneNumber = '25472054919') AS delivery_lat_log
FROM dual;
```

This assumes that each of your two queries returns a single value.  If not, then perhaps a `UNION` would be more appropriate:

```
SELECT
    shop_lat_log AS log_value,
    'shop_lat_log' AS log_type
FROM customers
WHERE phoneNumber = '254719401837'
UNION ALL
    SELECT
    delivery_lat_log,
    'delivery_lat_log'
FROM customers
WHERE phoneNumber = '25472054919'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UNION` for that:

```
SELECT `shop_lat_log` FROM `customers` WHERE `phoneNumber`='254719401837'
UNION
SELECT `delivery_lat_log` FROM `customers` WHERE `phoneNumber`='25472054919'
```

Note that the second query must have the same number of columns as the first query, and the results will have the **first** query's column names.

So even though you're selecting the `delivery_lat_log` column in your second query, the results will be in the `shop_lat_log` column if you're fetching an associative array.

Answer (score 1):

Use an SQL `case` statement

```
select case c.phone_number 
    when '254719401837' 
    then c.shop_lat_log
    when '25472054919'
    then c.delivery_lat_log
end as field
from customer as c
where c.phone_number in ('254719401837', '25472054919')
```

Comment: Good point, I added a where, but now it is repetitive, not sure if it would be better to to use `is null` stylistically.